# Swift Detecting a Change in a Textfield from a .xib file

Tags: swift, tableview, xib, textfield

My issue is that I have a textfield inside of an expandable table view, which is dictated by a cellDescription plist. In this table view, when the address portion is expanded, a textfield pops out where a user can input an address. The user must hit return (or enter) on the keyboard in order for the address to be saved. I was wondering if there was a method to detect a change in the textfield that can continuously update the textfield value, such that the user will not have to enter return to save the address. Below is how my code is currently structured, but I am confused because the textfield is not inside the regular view controller, but in an external xib file.

```
func configureTableView() {
    tblExpandable.delegate = self
    tblExpandable.dataSource = self
    tblExpandable.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    tblExpandable.register(UINib(nibName: "TextfieldCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "idCellTextfield")

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell


    if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idCellTextfield" {
        cell.textField.placeholder = currentCellDescriptor["primaryTitle"] as? String
        valueOfInterest = cell.textField.text!

    }


    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}

func textfieldTextWasChanged(_ newText: String, parentCell: CustomCell) {
    let parentCellIndexPath = tblExpandable.indexPath(for: parentCell)

    var address = ""

    address = "\(newText)"


    ((cellDescriptors[0] as! NSMutableArray)[11] as AnyObject).setValue(address, forKey: "primaryTitle")
    location = (((cellDescriptors[0]) as! NSMutableArray)[11] as! NSDictionary)["primaryTitle"]! as! String
    tblExpandable.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have text field in your CustomCell. So set an outlet of the text field in CustomCell class as:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var textField:UITextField!
```

Then set the CustomCell class as delegate of the textField and implement the required delegate method of the textField to detect the change in the value of textField.

Comment: How do I set the CustomCell class as a delegate of the textField because this swift file does not have an "override func viewDidLoad() {}"?

Comment: Why would you need viewDidLoad() method to set the delegate.You can set delegate either from xib file or in awakeFromNib() method of your custom cell class.

Comment: Attempting to set the delegate like: "textField.delegate = self" in awakeFromNib() results in an error when running in the simulator: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Have I not set the delegate correctly?

Comment: This may be because of textField does not initialize itself yet.Set your delegate after your view fully loaded. You can try other option here. Try to set delegate in Xib file, hope this will resolve your issue.